# TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not list - when trying to import in SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, tuples

I am getting "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not list - when trying to import in SQL Server" when trying to insert my data into SQL Server. How can I update my code? I tried changing "records = df_data.values.tolist()" to "records = df_data.values.totuple(), but no success. Adding in more text for text requirements on this post as it says that my post is mostly code and wants me to add more details.

**Edit: Updated code**

```
import yfinance as yf
import glob
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import os
import sqlite3
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Empyz\Desktop")


list1=['2022-03-18', '2022-03-25', '2022-04-01', '2022-04-08', '2022-04-14', '2022-04-22', '2022-05-20', '2022-06-17', '2022-07-15', '2022-10-21', '2023-01-20', '2024-01-19']

gme = yf.Ticker("gme")

for date in list1:
    df = gme.option_chain(date)
    df_call = df[0]
    df_put = df[1]
    
    df_call.to_csv(f'C:\Empyz\Deskop\\call_{date}.csv', index=False)
    df_put.to_csv(f'C:\Empyz\Deskop\\put_{date}.csv', index=False)
         
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob(f'*.{extension}')]

#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
#export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv( "Options_Data_Combined.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
print(combined_csv)



conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=localhost;'
                      'Database=Stocks;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

c = conn.cursor()

table_name = "Options_Data_GME"

# create table. I'm lazy so everything is just set to text
c.execute(f'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [{table_name}] (contractSymbol nvarchar(50), lastTradeDate nvarchar(50), strike decimal(18,4), lastPrice decimal(18,4), bid decimal(18,4), ask decimal(18,4), change decimal(18,4), percentChange decimal(18,4), volume float, openInterest float, impliedVolatility float, inTheMoney nvarchar(50), contractSize nvarchar(50), currency nvarchar(50))')
conn.commit()

combined_csv.to_sql(table_name, conn, if_exists='replace')


c.execute(f'''  
SELECT * FROM {table_name}
          ''')

for row in c.fetchall():
    print (row)
```

Comment: copying and pasting gives me the error `df_data = df[columns]
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not list`. What is it you're actually trying to achieve here? The end-goal is not clear and the question itself is misleading as there is no SQL involved in your code. Can you update your question with a specific end-goal?

Comment: Hi - I am trying to take the data from that csv file and upload it to my SQL server, but when I try that, I get the tuple error. I'll update the rest of the code now, thank you.

Comment: Just added the rest of the code

Comment: Side point: you should really specify all columns you are inserting into in the SQL. What would happen if someone moved around the columns on the base table?

Comment: all the columns are already specified in the script in step 2

Comment: You're missing the point that Charlie is making, which is that in your SQL statements you do not specify the column names. You *do* in the dataframe part, but if someone reorders the SQL table columns, your SQL logic breaks.

Answer (score 0):

So the easy way is to just use panda's `df.to_sql()` method. See the docs [here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

See the code below for a simple implementation using a local `sqlite3` database. You should be able to easily adapt this to a `pyodbc` connection.

Note that I've removed your comments and added my own so it's easier to see what I'm doing.

```py
import yfinance as yf
import glob
import pandas as pd

import sqlite3

FILEPATH = "./"                                                       ###### EDITED

list1=['2022-03-18', '2022-03-25', '2022-04-01', '2022-04-08', '2022-04-14', '2022-04-22', '2022-05-20', '2022-06-17', '2022-07-15', '2022-10-21', '2023-01-20', '2024-01-19']

gme = yf.Ticker("gme")

for date in list1:
    df = gme.option_chain(date)
    df_call = df[0]
    df_put = df[1]
    
    #outputs options data to csv based on dates and type
    df_call.to_csv(f'{FILEPATH}call_{date}.csv', index=False)         ###### EDITED
    df_put.to_csv(f'{FILEPATH}put_{date}.csv', index=False)           ###### EDITED
        
extension = 'csv'


# use f-strings instead of .format()
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob(f'{FILEPATH}*.{extension}')]    ###### EDITED

# create dataframe with all the CSVs combined.
combined_df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])

# using sqlite3 to create a test db
conn = sqlite3.connect('test_database')
c = conn.cursor()

table_name = "Options_Data_GME"

# create table. I'm lazy so everything is just set to text
c.execute(f'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} (contractSymbol text, lastTradeDate text, strike text, lastPrice text, bid text, ask text, change text, percentChange text, volume text, openInterest text, impliedVolatility text, inTheMoney text, contractSize text, currency text)')
conn.commit()

combined_df.to_sql(table_name, conn, if_exists='replace')


c.execute(f'''  
SELECT * FROM {table_name}
          ''')

for row in c.fetchall():
    print (row)
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the reply. When I try this method, I get ValueError: No objects to concatenate, and I'm not sure why. 
edit: also, for conn = sqlite3.connect() should it be the server name or should it be the database name? I've been avoiding to_sql since it hasn't worked for me in the past.

Comment: I changed the paths to the CSV files to suit my environment. You need to change the lines that deal with the CSV files to suit your file/path structure. As for the `sqlite3.connect()` you need to replace that with the similar `pyodbc` method to build the connection. I just didn't want to set up a working SQL server on my end. As stated, it should™ work exactly the same though. As for `to_sql`, it's a quick and easy way to map a dataframe to a SQL table. Just make sure the column names match on both ends (the dataframe end is easier to fix, just change the CSV column header)

Comment: also note that you need to make sure the table that gets created actually has the correct column datatypes. As stated, I used `text` as I was being lazy, and I don't know exactly which data types you want to use. See [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp) for reference...

Comment: Hi - I've changed the file paths and changed the connection to sql using pyodbc, but when I run the script, I get a "ValueError: No objects to concatenate"

Comment: I've edited 4 lines, denoted with a comment `###### EDITED` at the end of said line. I think your issue is still with the filepaths as it seems the `all_filenames` ends up as an empty list in your current logic. Try printing it out before updating your code with the changes I made to mine, to check if my assumption is correct...

Comment: The file paths were good, but I realize that the import os and os.chdir were missing. I added those back in right now, but now I'm getting "ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Options_Data_GME'. (102)")" which doesn't really make sense to me since the c.execute statement that you wrote out looks correct to me.

Comment: looking at my code, and comparing it to the code in your question, I think I know. In the line that starts with `c.execute(f'CREATE TABLE` replace `{table_name}` with `[{table_name}]`

Comment: I've updated my code in the main post. I made the edits that were suggested, but I'm still getting the same syntax error near the keyword IF. Even if I comment that section out (since the table already exists in my database), I get a different error: "DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")"

Comment: that error makes no sense with the code provided... I mean, there's no SQL statement that even closely matches what the error reports. Please note we only know whatever you tell us. If you are running code that is different from what you provide us, we will never be able to help you resolve it...

Comment: That's why I am confused as well. The code in the main post is the one that I am currently using, and it gives me that errors above.  I am using Spyder via Anaconda if that is relevant information. I just ran the script again, and I still get the error "ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Options_Data_GME'. (102)")" even after changing {table_name} to [{table_name}]